# ROS move_base costmap not connected error

Tags: navigation, move-base, costmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using ROS indigo running on 64bit Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. In the project, the nodes and visualisation (Rviz) seems to be functional when I launch the launch file I written. Here are the sensors used in the the project, which is a modified electric scooter:

- Hokuyo Lidar
- Phidgets Encoder

When I start moving the scooter using the joystick, the scooter will move physically, but in Rviz, the object detected by the lidar moves to the scooter, instead of the scooter moving in the map. When I did *roswtf*, it shows that the robot footprint is disconnected, though the rqt graph shows otherwise. Please advise on the possible ways that I can undertake to debug this issue.
[image: roswtf screenshot]

Here are the node connections. For the navigation stack, I'm using the Teb local planner instead of the default planner.

[image]

A screenshot of the tf tree:

[image]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246233/ros-move_base-costmap-not-connected-error/) by [photon](https://answers.ros.org/users/28317/photon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 68 on 2016-10-23

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This error is not related to `tf` it's saying that a pub-sub connection related to the footprint topic is not connected. This sometimes happens but likely will not effect your system. A workaround to trigger a reconnect is to create a new subscriber for the topic using `rostopic echo ...`

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-09-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1